# What is wrong with this python code

Tags: python

```
print ("You have two choices:", \n "(1) Get up now", \n "or," \n "(2) Sleep some more and wait till morning")
```

I really don't see what is wrong with this code. When I run it, Python says that *"there is an unexpected character after line continuation character"*, which I do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to fix your problem, note that the newline character `\n` should be **inside** the quote marks, i.e. part of the string literal itself:

```
print ("You have two choices:\n(1) Get up now\nor\n(2) Sleep some more and wait till morning")
```

---

Secondly, the reason for the error message is that the backslash `\` **outside** quotes is used to mean *"this logical line continues on the next physical line"*, i.e. [explicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining). This means that e.g.:

```
if some_really_long_predicate and \
        this_other_thing:
    print("We're here now")
```

is acceptable, although implicit continuation inside parentheses [is preferred](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

```
if (some_really_long_predicate and
        this_other_thing):
    print("We're here now")
```

Therefore when Python parses:

```
print ("You have two choices:", \n ...
                              # ^ continuation character
```

it is not expecting to find the `n` (the *"unexpected character"* in question), or any subsequent character.

---

Finally, note that you can use *multiline strings* to write it out more neatly:

```
print("""You have two choices:
(1) Get up now
or
(2) Sleep some more and wait till morning""")
                                       # ^ note triple quotes
```

(see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60369/32391) for how to make this neater in indented blocks).

Answer (score 2):

Put the newline character inside double quotes.

```
In [44]: print("You have two choices:",  "\n(1) Get up now",  "\nor,"  "\n(2) Sleep some more and wait till morning")
You have two choices: 
(1) Get up now 
or,
(2) Sleep some more and wait till morning
```