# Pink highlight in sublime after "\"

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

So Sublime Text started to do this:

[image: Sublime Text showing pink highlighting]

I'm coding in Python in SublimeREPL. It only happens with Python, so it's not an issue with the theme/color scheme.

How do I get rid of that?

**Edit:** So I get that \ is improper syntax, but my issue is when I get to this line in my code:

```
filepath = input('Enter file path (note: use \\\ instead of \\)\n')
```

I don't know how to print that withought having it look awful

Comment: Presumably it's indicating that those characters aren't valid syntax (as they follow the line continuation character - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29061670/3001761). Why were you including those backslashes?

Comment: Well, I actually noticed it when I ran my code, and in the output console, I printed this statement: "Enter file path (note: use \ instead of \\)" Which now looks like this. http://puu.sh/gELut/f3a8f07164.png

Comment: So it's in the **output**, not your **code**? You say it *"started to do this"* - what else changed (updated, settings, etc.)?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was messing around with color schemes earlier, and I installed sublimelint for the first time, but I removed it. And no, it's in both the output and the code.

Comment: It happens because it is not proper python syntax. Normally, those mean a string is unescaped and not close such as `"This is an invalid string\"`. Also, Python comments start with `#` not `\\ ` if that is what you are trying to do. Even JavaScript comments start with `//` (two forward slashes) not backward slashes

Comment: No, it's not that. It's just that my print statement looks awful. How do I print the "\" character then? I tried to escape it like \\ but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Self-promoting own project, but it actually solves the problem</sup>

Check out the [PythonImproved](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Improved) project, which provides a replacement language definition for the (actually pretty lousy) one shipped with Sublime. It's available through Package Control and [Github](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved). Here is all of your example text in a normal Python view:

[image: Python]

and with Python Improved:

[image: Python Improved]

<sup>Syntax highlighting - [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), of which I'm also the maintainer. It fully supports Python Improved, along with a bunch of other stuff.</sup>

So why was this happening? As you said, the text you entered was not valid Python code, but instead of ignoring it the built-in Python syntax definition highlighted it as `invalid.illegal.unexpected-text.python`. This is because the `\` character can be used as a line-continuation character (for example, your string literal is too long for one line, so you continue it on the next). However, when used, it's supposed to be the last character on the line before the newline. I (or one of the project's contributors) removed this section entirely from Python Improved, although I can't remember at the moment why - it must have been causing bugs elsewhere.

At any rate, I would highly encourage you to use PI anyways. The built-in Python definition is broken in so many ways it's hard to keep track of them - 
lack of Python 3 support, lack of consistency in which keywords and built-in function names are defined how, non-robust matching of many legal class and function definitions, no support for some language features, and more.
Python Improved has endeavored to fix all of that, plus add many additional features - they're all listed in the README. We're also working on full Unicode support for all Python identifiers - something that no other language definition currently has, except for one (and we got advice from its developer). A new release should be out pretty soon.